# Why do MX Linux doesn't appear on my boot menu?

Tags: linux, boot, partition, dual-boot, mx-linux

I've recently decided to update my MX Linux 18 to the 19 version. The thing is, I've downloaded the iso file, wrote it on a USB, boot MX Linux from my USB to install it on my disk, but after all that, I can't boot MX Linux from my disk since it doesn't appear on my boot menu.

I've restarted those steps several times, but nothing has changed. I've took a screenshot from gparted to show that I'm trying to install MX Linux on the 474.66 GiB partion (rootMX19).

What could be possibily wrong ?

Thank you. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-run your boot-manager (e.g. grub) to install the correct boot sector on your disk (try to install directly to `/dev/nvme0n1`, not the first partition `/dev/nvme0n1p1`)